# Image Swapping in pdf files in java

Tags: java, pdf

I have a PDF file containing more than 50 images and text. What I want is to swap the some images from that file. Means need to generate the list of images from the PDF file and select the image which i want to swap with my image at same place and with same resolution.

Thanx in Adv. Any type of help will be appreciated.